Determining if corrupted tar file is recoverable
I have a .tar file that when I attempt to extract or list the contents using the tar command I get the error: "Unrecognized archive format". I used the file command (within git-bash since it is not installed on my Windows machine) to see if maybe the archive type was mislabeled. When I run file on a good archive I get simply POSIX tar archive (GNU). On the corrupted file I get the following output:
POSIX tar archive (GNU), directory \303J8, mode 0000775, uid 0023420, gid 0000765, size 00000000000, seconds 14656555335, user radmin, group work

All of the extra output is strange and mostly meaningless to me. Does this extra output indicate anything useful? Any chance this file is recoverable?

"Any chance this file is recoverable?" - Only if say the SHA256 matches the original file.  If the file is corrupt then without an ability to repair the archive you are likely out of luck. Do you have something like PAR2 files at your disposal?

@Ramhound I don't have the original file to compare. I don't know what PAR2 is and this is a very locked down system, so I would assume not. Unfortunately sometimes the answer to "how do I do this" is simply "you can't".

Have you tried opening it with another program, maybe 7-Zip?

@AndrewMorton I have. 7-zip goes through the slow process as if it's extracting, and then when it gets to the end it fails.

If you kill 7-Zip before it fails, can you find any (temporary/intermediate) files it's created?
